# How to declare type limit when using generic type in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics

I'm trying to write a helper method to register `UITableViewCell` classes.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellClass:(NSArray<Class> *)cellClassArray {
    [cellClassArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Class _Nonnull cellClass, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *_Nonnull stop) {
      if ([cellClass isSubclassOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
          [tableView registerClass:cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([cellClass class])];
      }
    }];
}
```

It would be better if I can limit the type of `Class` in the generic declaration part for `NSArray` to be subtype of `UITableViewCell`.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't do that in Objective-C.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do that in Swift either. There are probably much easier ways to write this.

Comment: Yes, I can pass in `NSArray<NSString *> *` which is an array of class names and do more checking in my code. But I was looking for using the power of compiler.